# Calling ActionListener twice

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, actionevent

I feel like there's an easy solution to this but for some reason, I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a situation where one button has to be clicked first in order for another one to be clicked. The options the user chooses for those 2 JButtons will determine the program's next step. This would mean I'd have to call actionListener twice, right? How would I do this in one actionPerformed method?

I don't think I could do `if (e.getSource() == square[1][4] && e.getSource() == up) { }` in the actionPerformed method...

**EDIT**: I have a board of 4x4 buttons that I made using a 2d array of JButtons and they contain 2 pieces. I also have 4 JButtons to represent north, east, south, west. The user has to click a piece on the 4x4 board and then click the direction in order for the piece to move.

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements actionListener
{
    // other variables listed

    private JButton[][] square;

    private boolean circleSelected = false;
    private boolean triangleSelected = false;
    
    // other irrelevant methods
    
    public void actionPerformed(actionEvent e)
    {
        // I don't know how to go about this part 
    }
}
```

If it's needed, I have square[0][0] containing the circle piece and square[2][3] containing the triangle piece. However, since the x and y will keep changing, I don't want to specify the exact placement. Instead, I'd rather determine the `circleSelected` variables from the image that's clicekd i.e. if the user clicks on the button[x][y] that has an image of a circle on it, then `circleSelected = true` if that makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This would mean I'd have to call actionListener twice, right?

Not quite. You shouldn't directly call an ActionListener once but rather these listeners should respond to user action only.

> I don't think I could do `if (e.getSource() == square[1][4] && e.getSource() == up) { }` in the actionPerformed method...

Correct, this would be very wrong since the ActionEvent's source property refers to one and only one object.

---

Likely what you should do is use a private instance field of your class, or multiple fields, to hold state information that is used in your listeners. In other words, have a variable or variables hold information that tells the class if a button has been pressed previously, which button, etc, and then base what happens in a listener by what is held by these state variables. For more specific details and answers, please consider asking a more specific question, including pertinent code, preferably a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

As an aside, most buttons should have their own listener, often as an anonymous inner class.

Aside #2: if a button should not be pressed until another button is pressed, then that button, or its Action, should be disabled until it is supposed to be pressed. This can be changed by calling `.setEnabled(...)` on the button or on its Action (if it has an Action).

For example, try compiling and running the code below. Here I use `firstButton` as my *state* field, the one that changes the behavior of the ActionListener. You can use booleans, or any instance fields of the class for this purpose:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel {
    public static final int ROWS = 4;
    private JButton[][] square = new JButton[ROWS][ROWS];

    private JButton firstButton = null;
    
    public Board() {
        JPanel squarePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS, ROWS));
        for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < square.length; j++) {
                String text = String.format("[%d, %d]", j, i);
                square[i][j] = new JButton(text);
                square[i][j].setFont(square[i][j].getFont().deriveFont(32f));
                square[i][j].addActionListener(e -> squareListener(e));
                squarePanel.add(square[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(squarePanel);
    }
    
    private void squareListener(ActionEvent e) {
        if (firstButton == null) {
            firstButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
            firstButton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            JButton secondButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
            secondButton.setEnabled(false);
            String text = "First Button: " + firstButton.getActionCommand() + "; Second Button: " + secondButton.getActionCommand();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, text, "Selected Buttons", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            for (JButton[] row : square) {
                for (JButton button : row) {
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            firstButton = null;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new Board());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've added some code on the original post and I'll definitely have a look at `.setEnabled()`

Comment: Thanks - this has really helped! I just want to ask what the `for (JButton[] row : square) { for (JButton button : row) {}}` does? I'm new to Java (and programming in general) so I don't understand what its purpose is exactly

Comment: That is using nested for-each blocks to iterate through the square 2D array (probably should be re-named "squares"), resetting each JButton so that it is enabled.

Comment: Oh ok! If I had the direction buttons (they're buttons using a border layout) outside the 2D array though (since it's the 2nd button users have to click rather than another square on the grid) how would that look?

Answer (score 2):

just create a boolean variable isButtonOneClicked that can show if the first button is clicked and if Button 2 is Clicked and the variable's value is true then your next actions will be performed

```
boolean isButtonOneClicked=false;
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
        isButtonOneClicked=true;
  }  
});
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
      if(isButtonOneClicked){
          //perform next steps
       }
       else{
            // button 1 isn't clicked 
            // can't proceed to next Steps

       }

  }  
});
```